# How to investigate what slows down Windows 10 login?

Tags: windows-10, performance, login, lag

**Context**

I've recently installed a new Windows 10 (19042).
After install I noticed and really enjoyed that in the logon screen after I typed my password and pressed enter, the desktop showed up **instantly**.

I've installed Office and some other things, and now this instant increased to approx. 4-5 secs. I wanted to investigate what thing or things are causing the slowdown to decide it does worth or not.

It does not matter if I wait even 10 minutes between the computer start and the logon: it is still 4-5 secs. I've concluded that this is not about the Services or any busy state after start, instead the logon itself or the explorer (the shell). (Am I miss something here?)

The logon account what I am using is a local computer account, not a Microsoft account.

I started autoruns64 and examined the Logon and Explorer tabs. Many candidates are there.

**Issue / Question**

I've unchecked *all* on both tabs, and the logon delay did not changed at all, still 4-5 secs.
How can I investigate further what causes the logon delay, or am I misusing autoruns64 in this experiment?

Comment: did you have antivirus installed when it was instantaneous? what apps are running in the notification area of the desktop?

Comment: Many thx for the questions. Regarding antivirus, the built in AV was installed when it was instant, and now nothing changed. Regarding the notification area: If I uncheck everything using autoruns64, then the notification area is empty

Comment: @g.pickardou check for startup programs in task manager - they may also cause slowing down ; disable the ones you do not use

Comment: I would start with a boot Process Monitor Log to get an overview of activity.  Move onto an ETL boot trace if needed.

Comment: Many thx. It is the HP 1510 factory driver (via windows update). If I completely uninstall printer the login experience is instant, if I reinstall then 4 sec lag on login. Nothing else installed for the printer, than the windows update driver